# How can I store 2 different cheerio parsed objects into variables to work with them simultaneously for comparing them?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, electron, cheerio

In an electronJS app's "main.js" file on server side, I am using cheerio package for parsing the contents read with fs from 2 different HTML files, where both contain (various, but let's just say) 1 < ul> element that has different < li> elements on each file, so it requires a comparison (where I assume that it is mandatory to treat cheerio variables with parsed data as jQuery variables or with jQuery syntax)

```js
  //compare:
  comparedListA.each(function (index) {
    ...
  });
```

and other further steps (like a sync, but that's for later).

My problem is that I'm not having success at storing the cheerio's current parsed or loaded data  neither in variablesTypeA and variablesTypeB after reading sequentially the 2 HTML files with fs. Or, specifically, I get this error  when using the variables with the .find() method that works on cheerio and on jQuery (that currently is not imported).

[Image of error with .find() or syntax](https://i.stack.imgur.com/976hw.png)

Here is my code when I try to do the comparison on the server side "main.js" without importing jQuery by any of the 2 WAYS mentioned, and, in the end, I get the above error.

**main.js**

```js
const {
  app,
  Menu,
  shell,
  ipcMain,
  BrowserWindow,
  globalShortcut,
  dialog
} = require('electron');
const fs = require('fs');
var cheerio = require('cheerio');
//----------------------------------------------------------------------
var UpdatedFromDailyFeedFile = "UpdatedFromDailyFeedFile.html";
var StorageFileCustomizedBasedOnTemplate = "index.html";
var comparedBodyA;
var comparedBodyB;

fs.readFile(UpdatedFromDailyFeedFile, function(err, data) {
    var $ = cheerio.load(data.toString(), { decodeEntities: false });
    comparedBodyA = $('body');
});

fs.readFile(StorageFileCustomizedBasedOnTemplate, function(err, data) {
    var $ = cheerio.load(data.toString(), { decodeEntities: false });
    var jsFileOfHTML = './index.js';
    // check here that the JS file exists before linking it to the HTML file to be rendered
    // if there is no JS file already linked to the HTML file, then link it
    if($('body').find('#js-script-link').length==0){
      // $('head').append(`<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' https:; 'script-src-elem' 'self'; manifest-src 'self'">`);
      // $('body').append('<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>');
      $('body').append('<script id="js-script-link" src="'+jsFileOfHTML+'"></script>');
    }
    comparedBodyB = $('body');
});
//----------------------------------------------------------------------

  //Select both <ul> lists and do the comparison:
  //selecting the 3rd <ul> on the body:
  comparedListA = comparedBodyA.find('ul.section.img-text').eq(2);
  comparedListB = comparedBodyB.find('ul.section.img-text').eq(2);
  
  //compare:
  comparedListA.each(function (index) {
      firstLi = $(this);
      secondLi = comparedListB.eq(index);

      if (firstLi.html() === secondLi.html()) {
          console.log("same "  + firstLi.html());
      } else {
          console.log("different first:"  + firstLi.html() + " second: " + secondLi.html());
      }
  });
```

As the main.js is doing almost all the work, the index.js and index.html can have some generic content right now.

Comment: You may want to look at [the documentation for `readFile`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fsreadfilepath-options-callback); if you pass the `encoding` option, `data` is a string. Otherwise, it's a `Buffer`, and I don't believe calling a `Buffer`'s `toString()` decodes it into a string, but rather results in a comma-delimited list of bytes. Also, it appears you're using `comparedBodyA` before the callback has been called, which means it's undefined.

Comment: Repost of [How can I store 2 cheerio parsed objects in vars and use them with its jQuery library-like syntax (which Idk the best way to import it on electronJS)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74065876/how-can-i-store-2-cheerio-parsed-objects-in-vars-and-use-them-with-its-jquery-li). Please edit your existing question rather than reposting it.